# How can I use textbox textchanged events to change user input classes?

Tags: vb.net

InputValue1,..OperationAdd are instances of the class InputNumber. How do I assign my Inputvalues to the corresponding textboxes as option Strict On is activated?

```vb
Class MainWindow

    Dim InputValue1 As New InputNumber
    Dim InputValue2 As New InputNumber
    Dim ExpectedResultValue As New InputNumber
    Dim OperationAdd As New InputNumber

    Private Sub TBoxNumber1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TBoxNumber1.TextChanged
       TBoxNumber1.Text = InputValue1 'There is an error in this line, value of type InputNumber 'cannot be converted to a string
    End Sub
```

Below is the InputNumber Class:

```vb
Public Class InputNumber
    Inherits Input

    Private _number As Integer

    Public Property Number As Integer
        Get
            Return _number
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _number = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function Validate(s As String) As Boolean
        Dim isValid As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(s, _number)
        Return isValid
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You don't show InputValue1 New statement, only InputValue2.  You can put a breakpoint on the line giving the error, then hover over the InputValue1 to see its type and methods and values.

Comment: Are you keeping the definition of that `InputNumber` type a secret on purpose? Presumably it has some property that contains the actual number that you can get the data from or else you could call its `ToString` method. That said, that code makes no sense. Why would you be assigning something to the `Text` property every time the `Text` property changes? Surely you should be getting the `Text` rather than setting it.

Comment: @JBrooks He has declared InputValue1; it just wasn't formatted as code.

Comment: Show the code for the InputNumber class.

Comment: without definition of `InputNumber` help is not possible

Comment: Right, so it is as I said and that `InputNumber` class has a `Number` property that exposes the actual data so that is the property you should be getting in order to display it. It would also make sense to override the `ToString` method and have that return `Number.ToString()`. You could then use `TBoxNumber1.Text = InputValue1.ToString()` and you would not only get the correct value but also as the correct type. That code still makes no sense though. I suspect that it should be the other way around but who really knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should be getting the input from the `TextBox` into your `InputNumber` object, not the other way around. This:

```vb
TBoxNumber1.Text = InputValue1
```

should probably be this:

```vb
InputValue1.Validate(TBoxNumber1.Text)
```

When it actually comes time to display the value of that `InputNumber`, you would have to use `InputValue1.Number.ToString()`. Personally, I would add this to your `InputNumber` class:

```vb
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return Number.ToString()
End Function
```

and then you can use `InputValue1.ToString()` instead.

EDIT:

It's been pointed out that the `Validate` method is `Protected` so it can't be called like that. Unless there's some use for it in the `Input` base class, I'm not sure what it's for because, as it stands, you'd need to validate externally anyway, e.g.

```vb
Dim number As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(TBoxNumber1.Text, number) Then
    InputValue1.Number = number
End If
```

Comment: only problem that `InputValue1.Validate` is protected

Comment: @T.S., good point. I didn't notice that. One has to wonder what the point of that method is then. I'll update the answer with that in mind but the whole lot is a bit of a brothel.

Comment: Yes, InputValue1.Validate is protected, but I already got the clue to what I needed from the explanation above. It's actually InputValue1.Enter(TBoxNumber1). The Enter() method is defined in the base class, as you can see that InputNumber class inherits Input Class

Comment: I would hope that it would actually be `InputValue1.Enter(TBoxNumber1.Text)`. Forcing input from a `TextBox` rather than accepting any `String` makes the class much less useful. That said, if the parameter was type `Control` then you could still get the `Text` of any control but you still couldn't use it in a Console app.

Answer (score 0):

I am questioning the implementation of `InputNumber`. It does not make much sense in the current form. We don't know when validation is happen and `Number` is integer in fact.

I would do something like this.

```vb
Public Class InputNumber

    Private _number As Integer
    Private _hasNumber As Boolean

    Public Sub New(s As String)
        SetNumber(s)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Number As Integer
        Get
            Return _number
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property HasNumber As Boolean
        Get
            Return _hasNumber 
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub SetNumber(s As String)
        _hasNumber  = Integer.TryParse(s, _number)
    End Sub

    ' For consistency...
    Public Sub SetNumber(i As Integer)
        _hasNumber = true
        _number = i
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
       If HasNumber Then Return Number.ToString()
       Return String.Empty
    End Function
End Class
```

Then your usage will be (and I agree with @jmcilhinney, when you have `TextChange` event, you want to take a value from the text box and set a variable)

```vb
Dim inp As New InputNumber("ddd")
txtBox1.Text = If(inp.HasNumber, inp.Number.ToString(), "NO VALUE") '' example to use HasNumber

inp.SetNumber("sss")
txtBox2.Text = inp.ToString() '' Example to use straight value

inp.SetNumber(10)
Dim current As Integer = If(inp.HasNumber, inp.Number, -1) '' using as numeric value
```

Now, this class makes slightly more sense